# How to filter if start and end timestamp is between other start and end timestamp

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa

[Image of database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpuLk.png)

This is a database table. I have a reservation start and reservation end timestamp, it is from **2022-04-18 13:00:00** to **2022-04-18 18:00:00** (can be more). So, my problem is how to fetch this data, if i want to check if in this for example timestamp **2022-04-18 14:00:00** to **2022-04-18 15:00:00** is in this timestamp which is in **2022-04-18 13:00:00** to **2022-04-18 18:00:00**.

Example:
Reservation start 2022-04-18 10:00:00
Reservation end 2022-04-18 15:00:00
And i want to check this interval 2022-04-18 11:00:00 - 2022-04-18 13:00:00

It should filter from database and output this

```
reservation_id   user_email      desk_id  reservation_start    reservation_end
13               test@test.com   1        2022-04-18 10:00:00  2022-04-18 15:00:00
```

How to do this? In spring boot jpa, or in postgresql

Comment: if you want check that interval totaly within reservation period: interval_min_date >= Reservation_start and interval_max_date <= Reservation_end

Comment: if you want check that interval intersect reservation period: interval_min_date between Reservation_start and Reservation_end or interval_max_date between Reservation_start and Reservation_end

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but how to make, to only filter that day interval? Because interval can be longer than reservation_end, and i only want only that day, no other days

Comment: i don't understand, add example plz

Comment: This is example about what you said to try https://img001.prntscr.com/file/img001/n7VubhKBTMSvRTwe1XrUaw.png but, what if my interval_max_date is greater than reservation_end? I get nothing. My goal is, for example, person wants to reserve table from time 12:00 to 16:00, because of covid-19 in one hour interval can only be 10 reservations max.

Comment: Thats another story how i will make it, but for now i just need to fetch all reservations that collides in that time interval 12:00 to 16:00, like one reservation is from 10:00 to 13:00, and it should be shown in fetched data, and also reservation from 13:00 to 14:00 also, and 15:00 to 18:00 also.

Comment: And i only want reservations which is only on 2022-04-17, so i don't want reservations from other day, only from 04-17

Comment: what about my second comment about interval intersection?

Comment: also if you want working with time without day, you can use time type in postgres

Comment: Take all that information you scattered around in the comments and add to question as a coherent example with starting data and what you expect out.